# How to terminate tracepath when no-reply is returned?

Tags: shell, networking, trace

I'm writing a shell script (in Linux) to try to find all the IP address from one machine to another. Right now I'm scanning the network by limit the range of the possible IP addresses, but it won't be 100% accurate. There will be times hitting IP address that doesn't exists, when using `tracepath 192.x.x.x` will return me a long list of `no-reply` rather than waiting for it to eventually timeout. How do I quickly stop the current `tracepath` command inside a shell script ?

Is there anyway to read the output of the tracepath and detects if "`no-reply`" is returned, if so terminate the current `tracepath` IP address and moving on to the next one ?

Comment: There's not really an IP that doesn't exist. It's more that the IP at that particular hop does not respond to the trace packets.

Comment: @MarcB right, thanks for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `expect` to monitor the output of `tracepath` and do something when "no-reply" came out of it. Or maybe consider using `traceroute` which allows you to specify a maximum number of hops.